# Linear Regression

Tags: regression, econometrics

Consider the regression model:$$y=x\beta+u$$

Let us take expectations:$$E[y]=E[x\beta+u]=E[x\beta]$$
  by linearity of the expectations operator and $E[u]=0$
 .

We can write the above as$$\bar{y}=\bar{x}\beta$$

Now, by OLS, consider the fitted vector:$$\hat{y}=x\hat{\beta}$$
 Taking expectations, we have that $$E[\hat{y}]=E[x\hat{\beta}]$$
  I know that this should equal:$$\bar{\hat{y}}=\bar{x}\hat{\beta}$$

How does $E[x\hat{\beta}]=\bar{x}\hat{\beta}$
 ?

Comment: "I know that this should equal".... no, it shouldn't, actually.  Imagine $x=1$, so it effectively disappears from the equations.  Why do you think $\text{E}\hat{\beta}$ should equal $\hat{\beta}$?

Comment: Yes it does by the properties of linear projections. If x=1, then we regress on the constant, returning back the mean of y. The mean of the fitted value of y by OLS and the actual values of y are always the same.

Comment: This may be a problem with your notation.  Why do you think $\text{E}\hat{\beta} = $\hat{\beta}$?  Look carefully at the notation.  Consider that $\hat{\beta}$ is a random variable, as it depends on $y$, which is a random variable through $u$.   More to the point of your question, though, if say $x,y$ are random variables, what is $\text{E}xy$?